# How to wait for a Thread and Runnable using RequestFuture?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, runnable

I've `MyDataService` which collects data by multiple `GetSomeDataThread` in parallel. Each `GetSomeDataThread` requests data **synchronously** via `RequestFuture` and `StringRequest`.

I got a **timeout**. I solved it by **wrapping the request** with another `Thread` and `Runnable`.

The **timeout is gone**, but I'm now getting the data **asynchronously** (see the comments in `call()`).

I found a lot of good answers on SO, but no duplicate.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** To clarify the goal: `result[0]` should contain the content of `future.get()`, but it contains the default value `"nothing"`. I probably need to wait for `run()`  to finish, but don't know how.

**EDIT 2:** I can use a `StringRequest` (asynchronous) in `call()`, but not with future (synchronous). If I use `StringRequest` without wrapping it with another `Thread`, the app freezes and I'll get a timeout exception after a while (the URLs are fine).

```
public class MyDataService extends Service {
    // ... 
    protected Summary summary;

    protected void loadSummary() throws Exception {
        Collection<GetSomeDataThread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        // loop
        threads.add(new GetSomeDataThread("a"));
        threads.add(new GetSomeDataThread("b"));
        threads.add(new GetSomeDataThread("c"));

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads.size());
        List<Future<JSONObject>> results = executorService.invokeAll(threads);
        for (Future<JSONObject> result : results) {
            // do something with the result:
            // result.get()            
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

-

```
public class GetSomeDataThread implements Callable<JSONObject> {
    // ...

    public GetSomeDataThread(String actionId) {
        // ...
        url += "&actionId=" + actionId;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
        final String[] result = {"nothing"};

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
                requestQueue.add(request);

                result[0] = future.get();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, result[0]); // outputs the correct value, but delayed

                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });

        t.start();

        // TODO: wait for thread + runnable to finish 
        // t.join(); just blocks 

        // result[0] equals "nothing"
        return new JSONObject().put("result", result[0]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? That is what `result.get()` does.

Comment: What's your problem? What do you expect currently and what you would like to see?

Comment: @Oleg `result.get()` works fine, but not `GetSomeDataThread`. `call()` returns `result[0]`, which wasn't updated, because the update happens afterwards. I want `result[0]` to have the value of `future.get()`.

Comment: @azizbekian please have a look at my last comment to Oleg, who asked the same question. :-)

Comment: Why are you starting a new `Thread` in a task you invoke via `Executor` ? this doesn't make any sense. Waiting for `RequestFuture` to finish or waiting for the new thread you created to finish are the same. Only the later makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Oleg I had `RequestFuture` directly in the `call()` before, but I got only timeouts. How would you wait for `RequestFuture` in `call()`, without `Thread`?

Comment: The same way you do with it `future.get();` ?? Where are you getting timeouts?

Comment: @Oleg calling `future.get()` in `call()` gave me timeouts, that's why I wrapped it by another `Thread`.

Comment: @Oleg I just tested it with an asynchronous `StringRequest` in `call()`, which worked, but it need it synchronous.

Comment: Please edit your question, explain where are you getting timeouts, what you actually need and why.

Comment: @Oleg I added 2 edits to my question. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't help, everything you're doing doesn't make any sense, `requestQueue.add(request);` is already asynchronous you don't need `executorService` and you definitely don't need to create a `Thread` inside your submitted task.